# How to catch webview's swipe gesture in windows store app?

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps

Im building a windows store app (8.1) and I use webview control to load html files.I need to catch the drag/swipe event of the webview in the code behind. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use LinqToVisualTree to find the borders of webview and get the events for them.

so the code of the other response becomes:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var border = webView.Descendants<Border>().Last() as Border;

    border.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia ;
    border.ManipulationStarted += webView_ManipulationStarted;
    border.ManipulationDelta += webView_ManipulationDelta;
}

Point start;
void webView_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsInertial)
    {
        int threshold = 500;
        if (start.X - e.Position.X > threshold) //swipe left
        {
            e.Complete();

            //do something here
        }
    }
}
void webView_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    start = e.Position;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        webView.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia ;
        webView.ManipulationStarted += webView_ManipulationStarted;
        webView.ManipulationDelta += webView_ManipulationDelta;
    }

    Point start;
    void webView_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsInertial)
        {
            int threshold = 500;
            if (start.X - e.Position.X > threshold) //swipe left
            {
                e.Complete();

                //do something here
            }
        }
    }
    void webView_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        start = e.Position;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But the above code doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you but it's work well for me.

make sure your webview is show on screen and it's not behind any UI

Comment: glad to hear that it works for you. Don't know what I'm missing here. I tried using only a webview in the xaml like this   <WebView x:Name="wv"  IsHitTestVisible="True" ManipulationMode="All"></WebView> But still it doesn't work

Comment: btw I'm loading html file which is store in my local storage using  webview.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/path.html));

Comment: Can you share the project/solution which works for you?

Comment: This can't work since the Manipulation* events are not implemented for the WebView Control.   See msdn->WebView, section Remarks